# How do I remove a git branch whose name starts with a unicode character?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows

Using GfW I accidentally created a branch whose name begins with `<U+0096>`, which seems to be a unicode control-character.

```
$ git branch
  features/#72_some_branch
* features/#73_another_branch
  master
  <U+0096>features/#73_another_branch
```

Now, in order to correct this mistake, I need to know how to escape it in the git bash. I tried using the well known Alt+Num key combinations, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to admit, the answer was quite obvious. Using the built-in `echo` command of the bash shell, I was able to insert the desired symbol:

```
git branch -d "$(echo -e '\u0096')features/#73_another_branch"
```

Comment: This is a useful result

Comment: So you can't do `"\u0096features..."` directly?

Comment: I also tried this approach, but it did not work. It seems as if the git-bash doesn't espace these characters on its own. In my case it said `error: branch '\u0096features/#73_another_branch' not found.`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: there is a shell syntax here that is useful, but it's a bit odd. Not all shells implement it either. Using `$'text'` you can have the shell expand certain escapes: `\t` becomes a tab, `\r` a carriage return, and so on. Only octal expansions are allowed here though so for `\u0096` you need `$'\226'` (226 octal = 150 decimal = 0x96).

Comment: I have never seen this syntax before, so I testet it right away. It seems as if this emits another kind of char. Maybe this does use another charset or even another numerative than octal?